# Customizing varioref to only add "... on page XX", and only when there is more than one page in between reference and figure

Tags: cross-referencing, varioref

`varioref` is a nice package as it will, when referencing, add "... on the [facing/next/preceding/following] page" if the reference and figure (or whatever object is being reference) are located on different pages. If there is more than a page in between, `varioref` will add "... on page XX".

However, I've noticed that all these "... on the [facing/next/etc] page" becomes a bit excessive; what I only really need is the "... on page XX" when the reference is far away. In my document, I've solved this by redefining the appropriate TeX definitions of `varioref`:

```
\makeatletter
\vref@addto\extrasenglish{%
  \def\reftextfaceafter{}
  \def\reftextfacebefore{}
  \def\reftextafter{}
  \def\reftextbefore{}
  \def\reftextcurrent{}
}
\makeatother
```

However, it doesn't feel very robust as this only works if `english` is selected as option. For `american`, I would have to copy-paste the same commands but replace `extraenglish` with `extraamerican`.

Is there some more efficient and "thorough" way of achieving the same thing, but for all language options? It is really not necessary in my case since I know I will be using `english`, but I'm interested out of curiosity. =)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As those commands are defined in any of the `\extra...` commands of babel (if babel is being used) one needs to either apply such changes for all languages in use or (the better alternative) one patches `varioref` itself. Fortunately the commands are used only in a single place namely `\@@vpageref`. So a general solution would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@@vpageref} {\reftextfacebefore}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}
\patchcmd{\@@vpageref} {\reftextfaceafter}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}

% for \reftextafter and \reftextbefore we have to patch twice

\patchcmd{\@@vpageref} {\reftextbefore}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}
\patchcmd{\@@vpageref} {\reftextbefore}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}

\patchcmd{\@@vpageref} {\reftextafter}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}
\patchcmd{\@@vpageref} {\reftextafter}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}

\show\@@vpageref  % have a look at the results
\makeatother
```

It is a bit crude as`\@@vpageref` now contains some absolutely useless code, ie a bunch of if-then-else statements without any code inside to execute. But who cares ;-)

The above also nicely works if you just want to disable the "face" ones but keep the ones where turning a page is required.

### varioref + hyperref/nameref

If hyperref or nameref (a component of the hyperref bundle) is used in conjunction with varioref then the patching needs to be slightly different. In that case the macro that contains the calls is not `\@@vpageref` but `\NR@vprageref`. Furthermore it will get its definition only after `\begin{document}`, so the patch commands will look like this:

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\patchcmd{\NR@@vpageref} {\reftextfacebefore}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}%
\patchcmd{\NR@@vpageref} {\reftextfaceafter}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}%
\patchcmd{\NR@@vpageref} {\reftextbefore}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}%
\patchcmd{\NR@@vpageref} {\reftextbefore}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}%
\patchcmd{\NR@@vpageref} {\reftextafter}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}%
\patchcmd{\NR@@vpageref} {\reftextafter}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}}
\makeatother
```

**Important:** Even though this code is executed `\AtBeginDocument` it needs to be placed **after** `hyperref` was loaded, the reason being that `hyperref` also uses `\AtBeginDocument` to define `\NR@@vpageref`.

### varioref + cleveref (+ hyperef)

If the `cleveref` package is used then some more/different patching is needed as this package unfortunately uses yet another "private" copy of parts of the `varioref` code, sigh.
So in that case `\cref@old@@vpageref` needs to be patched, otherwise it is exactly the same approach:

```
\makeatletter

\patchcmd{\cref@old@@vpageref} {\reftextfacebefore}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}
\patchcmd{\cref@old@@vpageref} {\reftextfaceafter}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}

% for \reftextafter and \reftextbefore we have to patch twice

\patchcmd{\cref@old@@vpageref} {\reftextbefore}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}
\patchcmd{\cref@old@@vpageref} {\reftextbefore}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}

\patchcmd{\cref@old@@vpageref} {\reftextafter}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}
\patchcmd{\cref@old@@vpageref} {\reftextafter}{\unskip}{\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}{\typeout{*** FAIL ***}}
\makeatletter
```

### Update/Correction

As Gabriel pointed out, has initial idea as well as my generalization of it, i.e., patching the commands `\reftextafter`and friends to simply do nothing has the side effect that you will end up with an extra space. The reason for this is that this space is generated automatically by `\vref` after the first number with the assumption that some text (such as "on the next page") will follow. So the correct way to deal with this is to patch the commands not by  taking the mout but by replacing them with  `\unskip` thereby removing that extra space again.

In the above code that is already corrected!

Comment: A nice thing about this approach compared to mine is that I don't have the problem of possible trailing whitespace. However, this solution doesn't appear to work when `hyperref` is included in the document (the patch has no effect, although it says "SUCCESS" for all patches).

Comment: That is most certainly the case (that it doesn't work I mean). As hyperref changes the definitions of the vairoref internals you need to apply the same approach to the definitions in hyperef whatever they are), i.e., find the commands that execute `\reftextafter`and friends and patch them by taking the call out. Might add the corrsponding defs later .. have to run

Comment: added the patch for the hyperref case - not tested though

Comment: Hm, there's a problem: If the reference is at the end of a sentence, then a space will be included between the reference and the period.

Comment: @gablin send me a full "minimal" sample with the problem to frank.mittelbach at latex-project.org

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Is this still working? I am getting 6 times `***FAIL***` for my patches. I am loading `\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}`, `\usepackage[english]{varioref}`, `etoolbox` and `hyperref`.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi it does work here against TeX live 2013 sources. Have you patched \NR@@vpageref *after* begin document?

Comment: If you refer to `\AtBeginDocument{%`, yes.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi loading order makes a difference! the patch has come **after** loading hyperref - I added a comment into the answer

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\def\reftextfaceafter{\unskip}%
  \def\reftextfacebefore{\unskip}%
  \def\reftextafter{\unskip}%
  \def\reftextbefore{\unskip}%
  \def\reftextcurrent{\unskip}}
```

Comment: Does this also work when using multiple languages in the document? [Disclaimer: I haven't tested anything.]

Comment: This only works if babel is not used (or only used for a single language). The moment a language switch happens the definitions would get overwritten.

Comment: It should also replace the string not with *nothing* but with \unskip to account for the extra space separating ref and pageref data