# \RefWithPage LaTeX script to add page number only if farther than a threshold

Tags: pageref

**SHORT QUESTION:**

Is there already a LaTeX package adding a command \RefWithPage LaTeX script to add page number only if farther than a threshold?

**CONTEXT:**

Using the package `newfloat` to define some figures and tables that automatically move to the appendix for references, I used some basic commands such as
`\renewcommand{\refWithPage}[1]{\ref{#1}, page~\pageref{#1}}` and
`\renewcommand{\refWithPageInParenthesis}[1]{\ref{#1} (page~\pageref{#1})}`
to add page numbers to my mentions of such figures and tables (floats henceafter).

As I am moving such floats in and out of the appendix, I would like to free myself from deciding whether using `\ref` or `\refWithPage`, and consider extending a bit my commands to check the distance between the current page (`\the\value{page}`) and the page (`\pageref{...}`) where the float will end.

I am pretty sure I can program it, but rather than reinventing the wheel and adding yet another solution to those already existing, I tried to find one which already existed (did not find any) and thought I would ask quickly here.

Comment: You will need the refcount package (or hyperref) to compare \value{page} with a reference page number.  OTOH, I don't know of anyone who has implemented precisely what you want.

Comment: Probably not. Duplicate of [cross referencing - How to change Fancyref's page numbering behaviour? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136725/how-to-change-fancyrefs-page-numbering-behaviour)  (except that you're explicitly asking for a package. Your choice.) --actually on more searching there's https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44180/customizing-varioref-to-only-add-on-page-xx-and-only-when-there-is-more-t?rq=1 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36904/how-can-i-conditionally-include-the-page-number-in-a-cross-reference-when-the-o , looks cleaner.

Comment: I did not know the package "Fancyref", it does answer my question: thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the pointers in the comments, I was able to extend the solution to a similar question from [How to change Fancyref's page numbering behaviour?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136725/how-to-change-fancyrefs-page-numbering-behaviour) and to

1. move it to a package and
2. make the threshold distance a parameter of the package.

Here is an example of usage (to save in a file `test.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage[threshold=4]{faraway}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Dummy figure}
  \label{fig:dummy}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\Fref{fig:dummy} contains a dummy figure.
\clearpage
\Fref{fig:dummy} contains a dummy figure.
\clearpage
\Fref{fig:dummy} contains a dummy figure.
\clearpage
\Fref{fig:dummy} contains a dummy figure.
\clearpage
\Fref{fig:dummy} contains a dummy figure.
\end{document}
```

Because I gave a value of 4 to the threshold parameter in the example above, this generates a pdf document of 6 pages, such that

1. contains the Figure,
2. contains the text "Figure 1 contains a dummy figure."
3. contains the text "Figure 1 contains a dummy figure."
4. contains the text "Figure 1 contains a dummy figure."
5. contains the text "Figure 1 on page 1 contains a dummy figure."
6. contains the text "Figure 1 on page 1 contains a dummy figure."

Here is the code for the file `faraway.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{faraway}    
\RequirePackage{fancyref}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}

\define@key{faraway.sty}{threshold}[5]{%
  \ifnum#1 < -1
  \GenericError{Error!}{Threshold must be positive}
  \fi
  \def\kvfaraway@threshold{#1}%
}

\ExecuteOptionsX{threshold} % Provide the default value (5 here)
\ProcessOptionsX%

\newcommand{\ValueOfThreshold}{%
  \kvfaraway@threshold%
}

\renewcommand*{\reftextfaceafter}{\unskip}
\renewcommand*{\reftextafter}{\unskip}
\renewcommand*{\reftextfacebefore}{\unskip}
\renewcommand*{\reftextbefore}{\unskip}
\makeatletter
\let\saved@reftextfaraway\reftextfaraway
\renewcommand*{\reftextfaraway}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \def\ref@unknown@value{??}%
    \ifx\@tempa\ref@unknown@value
      \count@=0 %
    \else
      \count@\thevpagerefnum\relax
      \advance\count@ by -\@tempa\relax
      \ifnum\count@<0 \count@=-\count@\fi
    \fi
    \ifnum\count@<\kvfaraway@threshold%
      \unskip
    \else
      \saved@reftextfaraway{#1}%
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

(Kudos to @user31729 for his answer to
[Giving numerical value to a package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307723/giving-numerical-value-to-a-package) which was very helpful)